# STM32CUBEIDE "undefined reference to" Problem

Tags: c, stm32cubeide

I am trying to add StemWin to my project to drive a displayer. I could integrate LCD low-level hardware to the microcontroller. But when I want to use GUI functions it returns me an error “undefined reference to” for every function. Also, I am using a third party library. How come compiler doesn’t allow to use functions from the included library?

Comment: Did you `#include` the correct header file? Did you link the correct library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @r3mainer Yes. I have included the correct library and linked the header file from properties. But STM32CUBEIDE still throws me an error.

Comment: @r3mainer #include does not add the library. Arduino people believe in that because project configuration is visible for them (it is done by magical IDE)

Comment: @JCWasmx86 There is no solution in the link you provided. As I mentioned in the question summary, I am using the third party library and used it at different IDE without any problem.